# Robin Hood hashing

Tags: c, hash-map, c89

This is an implementation of a "string to int" hash table with [Robin Hood hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Robin_Hood_hashing). I have tested it as thoroughly as I could. It appears to have no bugs/leaks. I would appreciate any comments on correctness/performance/clarity. I have kept it ANSI C for simplicity.

```
/* robin_map.h */
#ifndef ROBIN_MAP_H
#define ROBIN_MAP_H
#pragma once

#include <stddef.h> /* size_t */

typedef struct robin_map
{
    size_t buffer_size;
    size_t element_count;
    void *data;
} robin_map;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

robin_map rm_init();

/* Initial size must be >= 5. Otherwise it is UB. */
robin_map rm_init_with_size(size_t size);

void rm_deinit(robin_map *map);

/* `key` and `map` cannot bu null. Null pointer cause UB */
int *rm_get(robin_map *map, char *key);
int *rm_put(robin_map *map, char *key, int value);

/* Returns removed value. Returns 0 if value not found */
int rm_remove(robin_map *map, char *key);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* ROBIN_MAP_H */
```

```
/* robin_map.c */
#include "robin_map.h"

#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum { false = 0, true = 1 } bool;

static void *xmalloc(size_t size)
{
    void *p = malloc(size);

    if (!p)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    return p;
}

static void *xcalloc(size_t count, size_t size)
{
    void *p = calloc(count, size);

    if (!p)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    return p;
}

static char *str_dup(char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str) + 1;
    char *duplicate = xmalloc(len);

    memcpy(duplicate, str, len);

    return duplicate;
}

/* Type of elements in a robin_map buffer */
typedef struct rm_element
{
    char *key;
    int value;
    unsigned psl; /* probe sequence lengths */
} rm_element;

static size_t strhash(char *str)
{
    enum { multiplier = 31 };
    size_t hash = 0;
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)str;

    for (; *p; ++p)
        hash = multiplier * hash + *p;

    return hash;
}

/* Allocates `size` elements and sets all values to null/zero */
static rm_element *alloc_elements(size_t size)
{
    /* calloc is not guaranteed to set pointers to null,
     * but it does work everywhere
     **/
    return xcalloc(size, sizeof(rm_element));
}

static bool slot_is_occupied(rm_element *slot)
{
    return slot->key != NULL;
}

static void rehash(robin_map *map)
{
    /* 
     * Since our hash algorithm is good, 
     * a growth factor of 2 should be fine
     **/
    enum { growth_factor = 2 };

    rm_element *old_buffer = map->data;
    size_t old_buffer_size = map->buffer_size;
    size_t i;

    map->buffer_size *= growth_factor;
    map->data = alloc_elements(map->buffer_size);

    for (i = 0; i != old_buffer_size; ++i)
    {
        size_t index;

        if (!slot_is_occupied(old_buffer + i))
            continue;

        old_buffer[i].psl = 0;
        index = strhash(old_buffer[i].key) % map->buffer_size;

        for (;; ++old_buffer[i].psl, index = (index + 1) % map->buffer_size)
        {
            rm_element *slot = ((rm_element *)map->data) + index;

            if (!slot_is_occupied(slot))
            {
                *slot = old_buffer[i];
                break;
            }

            if (old_buffer[i].psl > slot->psl)
            {
                rm_element tmp = old_buffer[i];
                old_buffer[i] = *slot;
                *slot = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    free(old_buffer);
}

static void grow_and_rehash_if_needed(robin_map *map)
{
    double max_load_factor = 0.7;
    double load_factor = ((double)map->element_count) / map->buffer_size;

    if (load_factor >= max_load_factor)
        rehash(map);
}

void rm_deinit(robin_map *map)
{
    rm_element *buffer = map->data;
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i != map->buffer_size; ++i)
        free(buffer[i].key);

    free(buffer);
}

robin_map rm_init()
{
    enum { initial_buffer_size = 47 };
    return rm_init_with_size(initial_buffer_size);
}

robin_map rm_init_with_size(size_t initial_buffer_size)
{
    robin_map map;

    assert(initial_buffer_size >= 5);

    map.data = alloc_elements(initial_buffer_size);
    map.buffer_size = initial_buffer_size;
    map.element_count = 0;

    return map;
}

static rm_element *rm_get_impl(robin_map *map, char *key)
{
    rm_element *buffer = map->data;
    size_t index = 0;
    unsigned psl = 0;

    index = strhash(key) % map->buffer_size;

    for (;; ++psl, index = (index + 1) % map->buffer_size)
    {
        rm_element *slot = buffer + index;

        if (!slot_is_occupied(slot) || psl > slot->psl)
            return NULL;

        if (strcmp(key, slot->key) == 0)
            return slot;
    }
}

int *rm_get(robin_map *map, char *key)
{
    rm_element *slot = rm_get_impl(map, key);
    return slot ? &slot->value : NULL;
}

int *rm_put(robin_map *map, char *key, int value)
{
    rm_element new_element;
    size_t index; /* Hashing _must_ happen after rehashing */
    bool key_is_duplicated = false;
    int *newly_inserted = NULL;

    grow_and_rehash_if_needed(map);

    index = strhash(key) % map->buffer_size;

    new_element.key = key;
    new_element.value = value;
    new_element.psl = 0;

    for (;; ++new_element.psl, index = (index + 1) % map->buffer_size)
    {
        rm_element *slot = (rm_element *)(map->data) + index;

        if (!slot_is_occupied(slot))
        {
            *slot = new_element;
            ++map->element_count;

            if (!key_is_duplicated)
            {
                slot->key = str_dup(slot->key);
                newly_inserted = &slot->value;
            }
            break;
        }

        if (new_element.psl > slot->psl)
        {
            rm_element tmp = new_element;
            new_element = *slot;
            *slot = tmp;

            if (!key_is_duplicated)
            {
                slot->key = str_dup(slot->key);
                key_is_duplicated = true;
                newly_inserted = &slot->value;
            }
        }

        if (!key_is_duplicated && strcmp(slot->key, new_element.key) == 0)
        {
            slot->value = new_element.value;
            newly_inserted = &slot->value;
            break;
        }
    }
    return newly_inserted;
}

static void rm_pop_element(robin_map *map, rm_element *slot)
{
    rm_element *buffer = map->data;
    size_t i = slot - buffer;

    free(slot->key);
    
    --(map->element_count);

    for (;;) {
        size_t prev = i;
        i = (i + 1) % map->buffer_size;

        if (buffer[i].psl == 0) {
            buffer[prev].key = NULL;
            break;
        } else {
            buffer[prev] = buffer[i];
            --(buffer[prev].psl);
        }
    }
}

int rm_remove(robin_map *map, char *key)
{
    rm_element *slot = rm_get_impl(map, key);
    int popped = 0;

    if (slot)
    {
        popped = slot->value;
        rm_pop_element(map, slot);
    }

    return popped;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hashing Weakness**

If `initial_buffer_size` is a power-of-2, the index becomes nothing more than a mask of the lower bits of the hash as in `% map->buffer_size`.  When hash is weak, using only a few bits results in poor overall hashing.  When `.buffer_size` is a prime more than 2, then index uses all the bits of the hash uniformly.

**Consider hiding `robin_map`**

If the initialization functions used a  *pointer*, then the details of `robin_map` can exist entirely in `robin_map.c`.  This is a *good* thing.  The caller only knows of a pointer to `robin_map`, not its members.

**`robin_map.h` lacks documentation**

Consider that a user may only see the .h file (or only cares to see the .h file).  Functions usage and limitations deserve comments there.  Perhaps add the wiki link there too.

**`double` math in an integer problem**

Consider using integer math.

```
// double max_load_factor = 0.7;
// double load_factor = ((double)map->element_count) / map->buffer_size;
// if (load_factor >= max_load_factor)
//   rehash(map);

unsigned long long max_load_factor_n = 7;
unsigned long long max_load_factor_d = 10;
if (map->element_count * max_load_factor_d >=  
    map->buffer_size * max_load_factor_n) {
  rehash(map);
}
```

**C vs C++**

`#ifdef __cplusplus` is a step towards usage with both C and C++.
With `#include <stddef.h>`, consider [Should I include stddef.h or cstddef for size_t](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5079325/2410359).

**More tolerant `rm_deinit()`**

Allow `rm_deinit(&map)` with `map.data == NULL`.  Perhaps as below. The point is that calling `rm_deinit()` deserve to be less prone to UB and cleans up `robin_map` more.

```
void rm_deinit(robin_map *map) {
  if (map) {
    rm_element *buffer = map->data;
    if (buffer) {
      for (size_t i = 0; i != map->buffer_size; ++i) {
        free(buffer[i].key);
      }  
      free(buffer);
    }
    map->buffer_size = 0;
    map->element_count = 0;
    map->data = NULL;
  }
}
```

**Spell check**

```
/* `key` and `map` cannot bu null. Null pointer cause UB */ 
                           ^
```

**Use `stdbool.h`**

Do not code unconditionally `bool, false, true`.

```
// typedef enum { false = 0, true = 1 } bool;
#include <stdbool.h>
```

**Other applications: Generalizing `x*alloc()`**

Consider clear defined behavior when `size == 0`.

**`unsigned` vs. `size_t`**

I'd expect `unsigned psl;` to use the same type as `size_t buffer_size;`.

**Overflow check missing**

```
 if (map->buffer_size > SIZE_MAX/growth_factor) Oops(); // Add like code
 map->buffer_size *= growth_factor;
```

**`const`**

Use `const` when the reference data does not change.  This conveys code intent better, allows for more application and sometimes select optimizations.

```
 // static size_t strhash(char *str)
 static size_t strhash(const char *str)
```

Other various functions too.

**Kudos**

- Good use of name space.
- Good use of *unsigned* math.

Comment: Thank you for the review. A couple points:

Comment: I did consider hiding robin_map behind a pointer, but that would have been two levels of indirection, so I ended up not doing it. I probably should have gone with it though.

Comment: I did consider replacing floating point math with integer math, but that might cause overflow, so I decided not to.

Comment: I restricted the project to ANSI C, and `<stdbool.h>` and `const` were added in C99 if I recall correctly. So, I intentionally didn't use them.

Comment: "would have been two levels of indirection" --> a second level is not needed.  Consider how `FILE *` works,

Comment: With `long long` math, as used in this answer, overflow is not a serious concern.

Comment: "restricted the project to ANSI C" Hmm, unclear why one is coding in 2021 to a 1980s standard.  Good luck.

Comment: To be honest, just to keep it simple. I find the cognitive load of the annotations a bit overwhelming, especially when learning about a data-structure/algorithm. (`const`, `[[nodiscard]]`, `noexcept`, `[[noreturn]]`, `thread_local`, `[[no_unique_address]]`, `[[maybe_unused]]`, [etc etc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes)).

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili OK, yet better to use [C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/attributes) documentation than [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) to understand C.

Comment: I have one more question: Why is making the deinitialization function more tolerant a good idea? Wouldn’t it simply mask logic errors?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Consider overall error handling, not just in deinitialization.  As code cleans up some mess, it needs to free resources, thus deinitialization is more likely purposely called with `NULL`, 0, etc.  "simply mask logic errors" --> Rather than hoping _undefined behavior_ exposes and error, actively detect trouble.  Note `free(NULL)` is OK.

Comment: Turns out `const` was a part of ANSI C. For some reason I was under the impression that it was added later on